# Why There Is Limited BIOS Revisions Displayed For My Laptop's Model?

Tags: bios, updates, dell-latitude, downgrade

There are actually many BIOS revisions available for my laptop's model - from **A04 to A08** and then from **A12 to A14 (latest to date)**. Albeit when signing in to DELL's website and navigating to download section of drivers and searching for BIOS updates, among all available I get **only 1 (A07) when searching by service tag** of my laptop and **only 2 (A07 and A14) when searching by my laptop's model**. Here is the picture of the latter:

[image]

*Why system does not display **all of BIOS revisions**?*

*Is this something tested and suggested and unique to each model that would guarantee correct functionality?*

At least that is what I thought of when searched first by service tag since although there are many BIOS revisions available for this model, it could be that some models should only be updated with certain revisions:

[image]

However when I searched by model number and got only 2 BIOS revisions available, it made me realize that it might just be website's error for not reporting all available updates and is not something unique to every model.

It has been stated that BIOS updates at least on DELL laptops are **irreversible and non-downgradable** which makes me be more cautious to not do something wrong and by this I mean, not updating to latest version available but one version earlier to see how my laptop will work with it, instead of updating to latest revision only to realize later it is buggy and awaits another BIOS revision where things are fixed which means waiting time because there is no way to downgrade BIOS.

What do you think SU geeks? Would you only apply website's suggested updates (A07 and A014) or any update which makes sense to you more?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you determine there are more than 2 for your model? I just checked the site (did not log in) and it only shows 2

Comment: @Moab Question updated

Comment: All I can suggest is to post this question on the Dell community forums, maybe a Dell employee will respond, since Dell is the only one that would really know why. More than likely is is an error on their part, usually there is a link on the driver page for "previous versions" which shows all available versions of the driver or bios that are available, but is missing in your bios section. I just tried pulling up the drivers page for a Dimension 5150, and it cannot find the drivers page? Looks like the server is having issues.

Comment: @Moab You're right, I better ask there.